# Book about a guy with uncontrolled telepathy skill

Tags: story-identification, books, telepathy

So the story goes more less like this.

There are some mathematical proofs (of a sci-fi nature) that telepathy is real, exists and that some people have it.

A guy is traveling around the country, and he mostly drives himself away from people.
That is important that he is away from people, because he can hear their thoughts and cant stop thoughts of other invade his mind. The more people, the worse and he got headaches, etc. I dont remember what he does, I think he is a reporter, but not sure, maybe an investigator, detective or a scientist.

He goes to a farm, not sure what happens there, but he finds a woman who owns it and they are about to have sex. Funny thing: he can’t hear her thoughts, that makes him relaxed and curious, but cautious. At the last moment she is about to blow him, he reads her mind and knows she have steel teeth and wants to snap his penis. So he runs away, etc, she chase him, I think he kills her in the end, but not sure.

Eventually he meets woman who can shield his mind, they fall in love instantly etc.

She is terminally sick, not sure on what sow what he does is -> he transport their mind into mind a a child / guy who is in coma and they live together in his mind.

If anyone remembers the title of this book, please tell me. I read it about 15 years ago and don’t remember the title nor author, but it was great book!

Comment: Telepathy, terminally sick wife, and transporting minds into a child/guy make me think of "Eyes I Dare Not Meet In Dreams" by Dan Simmons, from the collection "Prayers to Broken Stones".  Don't know about that other stuff, though.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayers_to_Broken_Stones

Comment: Huh. Bits of this remind me of Frank Robinson's [*The Power*](http://www.amazon.com/The-Power-Frank-M-Robinson/dp/0312866542) , parts remind me of Sturgeon's [*...And Now the News*](http://www.amazon.com/And-Now-News-Complete-Theodore/dp/155643460X) , and parts of it remind me of the uncensored tales of Hiawatha.

Comment: Well, the penis chomping with the steel teeth brings Philip Jose Farmer's *Image of the Beast* to mind, but the rest of the plot is a total miss.

Comment: The penis-chomping bit also happens in the Hyperion Cantos by Dan Simmons.Part of the character Fedmahn Kassad's story, I believe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two of the comments already mention Dan Simmons, but I'm pretty sure this is his book [*The Hollow Man*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hollow_Man_%28Simmons_novel%29).

> It narrates the story of a university lecturer who has the ability to "hear" the thoughts of others, an ability he shares with his dying wife.

Here's the steel teeth:

ch. *There Are No Eyes Here* :

> “Jesus!” He pulled back instinctively and opened his eyes the instant
>   her mouth snapped shut with a metallic click. Bremen saw the gleam of
>   razor steel between red lips and staggered backward again only to
>   crash into the bedside table, knocking the covered lamp over and
>   sending high shadows flying.

Comment: Just finished reading it. Excellent book.